# How do you find nodes in the animation workspace if scroll past them?

Tags: node-editor, animation-nodes, workspaces

I have zoomed out and scrolled past my node tree in the Animation nodes workspace now I can't find it is there any way to 'quick-travel' back to it?

Comment: Numpad , centers the view to selected nodes. If no nodes selected, press A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just answered my own question, can't seem to find a way to get an individual node but selecting all then 'numpad .' works.